# how to know when a link was opened by a user and when it was called by src atribute

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I am working on project which contains multimedia content embeded in iframe. For example video from streaming services like openload, verystream etc.

My goal is to "hide" original url of verystream behind my own internal url. I know that is not fully possible, because of devtools. You can look into headers. But only for most of the users.

I am using: Spring-Boot, Spring-security, Thymeleaf, jquery

I expect when iframe call that link it will redirect request to original(external) url. But when user open "/reload-link/pandora-hearts/5" in browser, postman etc. It will show him message or relocate him somewhere else.

```
<iframe src="https://verystream.com/e/7gj1LP1SJg7/"</iframe>
```

REPLACE WITH:

```
<iframe src="/reload-link/pandora-hearts/5"</iframe>
```

```
@GetMapping("/reload-link/{url}/{episode}")
public void returnUrl(@PathVariable("url") String url,
                      @PathVariable("episode")int episodeNum,
                      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){

            Anime anime = animeRepository.findByUrl(url);
            Episode episode = episodeRepository.findByAnimeRefAndEpisode(anime,episodeNum);
            String iframe = episode.getLink1();
            iframe = iframe.substring(iframe.indexOf("\"") + 1);
            iframe = iframe.substring(0, iframe.indexOf("\""));
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", iframe);
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);

    }
```

Comment: Why not issue them a token or cookie or something and if those aren't sent with the request, then it fails?

Comment: @VLAZ that should work. Thank you for your advice and how can I achieve that in proper way? propably ajax call? Do you have some working example please?